# Run android app on older API AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to support newer themes using values-11, values-14, etc.  For the application to compile, I have to increase the target API, but that removes the lower API AVDs from the selection list in the run configuration.  How do you get eclipse to run it on an older version to see if it works?  I'm sure I can load it manually but it seems Eclipse should allow this.

Comment: "but that removes the lower API AVDs from the selection list in the run configuration" -- I just tested an app with a build target of API Level 16, and with "Run Configuration" set to "Always prompt to pick device", I get the full slate of emulators, old and new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Eclipse will try to launch an AVD that satisfies your `targetApiLevel`, but if any AVD is running at or above your `minSdkLevel`, then it will use that instead.  But you need to make sure the AVD is properly registered with Eclipse.  In my experience, this usually would seem to mean not closing the AVD Manager window until the AVD is fully booted and showing the Home screen (or your app).

Comment: It looks like that works.  Setting it to "Always prompt to pick device" also allows selected an earlier one to start.  I think I'd call that a bug in the eclipse plugin.

Comment: I agree.  Bug filed, per your suggestion.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35367

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which API level to target, but also the minimum that will run the app, in `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="X" android:targetSdkVersion="Y" />`

The key is to specify the minSdk version too.

Comment: That still doesn't allow you to select the older AVD in the run configuration.  I think it might just be an oversight in the design.